# How to configure middlware in a class library type project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket

I am creating a class library project that will be responsible for wrapping up some communication over the web-socket. This library will then be consumed by some desktop (console/windows services) type applications. I am planning to use the WebSockets as explained in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  However, this shows examples of how to use this as a middleware where a Startup class could be used to Configure the services. If I want to use this in a class-library type project, what will be the best way of consuming this library because to my understanding a class library project cannot have a Startup class. Any links for examples of how to do it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: Hi @BrandoZhang It did help I am still struggling to make the whole end-to-end WebSocket server with a client all working together. Maybe I will post a separate question about the struggle but I am going to mark your suggestion as an answer. Sorry I missed to do it earlier but its people like you make this place so welcoming and helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you could directly create a service in that class library. There is no need to set the startup.cs `app.UseWebSockets`. You could specify in your codes that it needs WebSockets middleware.

For asp.net core usage, I suggest you could try to create a `SocketServiceCollectionExtensions` class like below, then you could register the service in that method like this and then other service could call this service's method by using DI.

```
public static class ServicesConfiguration
{
    public static void AddSocketServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.AddScoped<YourCustomSocketWorkableClass2>();
        services.AddScoped<YourCustomSocketWorkableClass>();
     
    }
}
```

Then you could register this service by using just one line:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSocketServices();
}
```